# Run android builds/gradle in background in terminal?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, gradle, terminal

I have a very big projects which takes north of two hours to compile. I do it on a VPS using a SSH terminal. Currently I run `./gradlew bundleRelease` and leave it for 2-3 hours. But I want to run it as a daemon to which I could leave and return to.

Just like how pm2 (js process manager) works except when it encounters an error I don't want it to restart. It's just that I'd like to leave the process running, having ability to tap into logs anytime to see the progress or errors with timestamp.

And if there's a way to send a email as well on failure that would be awesome.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you not using linux/unix `screen` or just setup a build server?

Comment: @MorrisonChang dang. that's it. that is what I needed for the background part. Thanks.
Also, is there any way to do that email thingy?

Comment: Would depend if your cloud hosted server allows outbound email. If email allowed, then wrap the gradle script in a linux/unix shell script and check for return value or something like check log for "success"/"fail" and email/message appropriately. Lots of tutorials on unix shell scripting online.

Comment: that sounds doable! thanlks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MorrisonChang had the correct answer. screen tool does the job fine for me. For the email thing, I'd have to create a shell script and watch for the outputs of the commands I run and send email on the basis of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
./gradle/gradlew -p apps :student:assembleDevDebug
```

student is your app folder name

Comment: What does it do?
How do I return back to it?
How do I watch the current status thorugh log?